# Understanding code generated by Yesod Persistent TH

Tags: haskell, yesod, persistent

I've spent a while trying to understand the code generated by template haskell in this example taken from the Yesod book:

```
share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
Person
    name String
    age Int
    deriving Show
Car
    color String
    make String
    model String
    deriving Show
|]
```

I feel like I mostly see what's going on (a lot of type marshalling), but one section still confuses me:

```
instance PersistEntity (PersonGeneric backend) where
  data instance Unique (PersonGeneric backend) =
  data instance EntityField (PersonGeneric backend) typ
      = typ ~ KeyBackend backend (PersonGeneric backend) => PersonId |
        typ ~ String => PersonName |
        typ ~ Int => PersonAge
  type instance PersistEntityBackend (PersonGeneric backend) =
      backend
```

The data instance `instance EntityField (PersonGeneric backend) typ` has three data constructors, which makes sense (one for each column in the database), but even after looking up what the tilde does in haskell, I can't understand what it's doing there. Why is the `=>`, normally used for universal quantification, used after something that doesn't seem to restict any types?

Please let me know if I can be more clear in some way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This syntax is used to declare GADT without GADT-syntax.

For instance,

```
data Z a b = (a ~ Int, b ~ Bool) => Z1 a b
           | (Show a, b ~ Float) => Z2 a b
```

is equivalent to

```
data Z a b where
    Z1 :: Int -> Bool -> Z Int Bool
    Z2 :: Show a => a -> Float -> Z a Float
```